# Retrieving data from applicationHost.config file using Linq To XML

Tags: iis, linq-to-xml

I am trying to obtain the value of 'dontLog' attribute below from the applicationHost.config file:

```
<location path="Default Web Site">
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <authentication>
                <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
            </authentication>
        </security>
        <httpLogging dontLog="false" />
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

I was able to read all 'location' nodes but LinQ to XML can be very confusing.
Here is my code:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> locationNodes = doc.Document.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "location").ToList();

foreach (XElement e in locationNodes)
{
    Location location = new Location()
    {
        Name = e.Attribute("path").Value
    };

    if (location.Name == "Default Web Site")
    {
        //not working
        IEnumerable<XElement> httpLogging = e.Elements().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "httpLogging").ToList();
        //need to obtain the value of 'dontLog' attribute and return null if not exist
    }
}

public class Location
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Thank you
Max

Comment: I'm curious as to why you don't use the `Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager` bits to for this?

Comment: because it is a pain to use those classes. I ended up using APPCMD.EXE tool to extract the data. A lot easier. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question doesn't give any indication of what happens when the program runs (other than it's not working), but most likely (based on playing with your code) you're not getting anything back, and this is because of the structure of your XML and how `.Elements()` works.  `.Elements()` returns "Returns a filtered collection of the child elements of this element or document".

The only child element of `<location>` is `<system.webServer>` - it never gets down to `<httpLogging>`, which is a child of `<system.webServer>`.

As with most things, there are multiple ways to accomplish what you're trying to do.  Here is one.

```
if (location.Name == "Default Web Site")
{

    string dontLog = (string)e.Descendants("httpLogging").Attributes("dontLog").FirstOrDefault();        
}
```

Notice a couple of things in the above code.  First, the call to `.Descendants("httpLogging")`.  Unlike `.Elements()`, `.Descendants()` will return all the *descendant* nodes of the current element, and by passing in "httpLogging") it will return all the descendant nodes that have that name.

Secondly, the explicit cast `(string)` will return null if the attribute doesn't exist (otherwise it will return the string value of the attribute).

Finally, based on the sample structure there will be only one `<httpLogging>` element for each group of `<location>`, so calling `FirstOrDefault()` will return the first occurrence, or the default value (null for reference types) if there isn't one.

Answer (score 1):

In VB .Net it would be

```
    Dim location As XElement
    'example given
    location = <location path="Default Web Site">
                   <system.webServer>
                       <security>
                           <authentication>
                               <windowsAuthentication enabled="true"/>
                           </authentication>
                       </security>
                       <httpLogging dontLog="false"/>
                   </system.webServer>
               </location>

    Dim dontLogValue As String = location.<system.webServer>.<httpLogging>.@dontLog
```